# find index of n consecutive values greater than zero with the largest sum from a numpy array (or pandas Series)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So here is my problem: I have an array like this:
`arr = array([0, 0, 1, 8, 10, 20, 26, 32, 37, 52, 0, 0, 46, 42, 30, 19, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0])`
In this array I want to find n consecutive values, greater than zero with the biggest sum. In this example with `n = 5` this would be `array([20, 26, 32, 37, 52])` and the index would be `5`.

What I tried is of course a loop:

```
n = 5
max_sum = 0
max_loc = 0
for i in range(arr.size - n):
    if all(arr[i:i + n] > 0) and arr[i:i + n].sum() > max_sum:
        max_sum = arr[i:i + n].sum()
        max_loc = i
print(max_loc)
```

This is fine for not too many short arrays but of course I need to use this on many not so short arrays.

I was experimenting with numpy so I would only have to iterate non-zero value groups:

```
diffs = np.concatenate((np.array([False]), np.diff(arr > 0)))
groups = np.split(arr, np.where(diffs)[0])
for group in groups:
    if group.sum() > 0 and group.size >= n:
        ...
```

but I believe this is nice but not the right direction. I am looking for a simpler and faster numpy / pandas solution that really uses the powers of these packages.

Comment: `rolling(n).sum()` is useful in Pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html#window-generic. You should similarly be able to use `rolling(n).min()` to identify any windows that contain a value < 0, so that you can exclude them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

N = 5
win = sliding_window_view(arr, N)
idx = ((win.sum(axis=1)) * ((win>0).all(axis=1))).argmax()
print(idx, arr[idx:idx+N])

# Output
5 [20 26 32 37 52]
```

**Answer greatly enhanced by chrslg** to save memory and keep a `win` as a view.

**Update**

> A nice bonus is this should work with Pandas Series just fine.

```
N = 5
idx = pd.Series(arr).where(lambda x: x > 0).rolling(N).sum().shift(-N+1).idxmax()
print(idx, arr[idx:idx+N])

# Output
5 [20 26 32 37 52]
```

Comment: What about the "greater than zero" part?

Comment: You don't see it in the question? stated - "I want to find n consecutive values, greater than zero with the biggest sum"

btw, I've never heard of `numpy.lib.stride_tricks` - good to know! :)

Comment: Two problems with your new answer (the one that takes into account the "greater than zero" part). 1. OP seams to be interested by index more than by the subarray itself (they print `max_loc`, not `arr[max_loc:max_loc+n]`). And you can't no longer find the index that way now that you have some missing lines in `view`. It gives the index in `view`, not the index in `arr`.

Comment: And 2. What is really interesting with `sliding_window_view` is the fact that it is a view. So even if you have 1 billion number, and want to search with a window n=100, it is not really a problem: it doesn't really create a 100 billions number 2d array, with lot of redundant values, just to search the sum. The view is just a view. It is the same 1 billion numbers, with no new memory used at all. (I mean, if your solution had been to actually create a len(arr)×n array, it would have been overly expansive, to add a whole dimension to data. But it does not, because it is just a view.

Comment: Except that now that you have added `view=view[condition]` to filter out the 0, now it is no longer a view. You litteraly allocate memory for len(arr)×n data. It ruins a little bit what made your solution (that I was about to post myself :D) great.

Comment: So, long story show, I would rather `((win.sum(axis=1))*((win>0).all(axis=1))).argmax()` from your original `view`, without the `view=view[...]` stage, to take into account that "greater than 0 part".

Comment: Wow, I really love this answer. I never heard of `numpy.lib.stride_tricks` before and it is exactly what I need. And the `*(win>0).all(axis=1)` trick makes it just perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, and a nice bonus is this should work with Pandas Series just fine.

Comment: Hi, @Corralien: One other fast way is to use cross-correlation: Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using cross-correlation, [`numpy.correlate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html), is a possible, concise and fast solution:

```
n=5

arr[arr<0] = np.iinfo(arr.dtype).min # The greatest negative integer possible
#Thanks for the np.iinfo suggestion, @Corralien

idx = np.argmax(np.correlate(arr, np.ones(n), 'valid'))
idx, arr[idx:(idx+5)]
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
n, l = 5, arr.size

arr[arr<0] = np.iinfo(arr.dtype).min # The greatest negative integer possible
#Thanks for the np.iinfo suggestion, @Corralien

idx = np.argmax([np.sum(np.roll(arr,-x)[:n]) for x in range(l-n+1)])
idx, arr[idx:(idx+n)]
```

---

Output:

```
(5, array([20, 26, 32, 37, 52]))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a really nice answer as well. I somehow forgot about the rolling window. I timed both answer and the `sliding_window_view` makes it about 15 times faster.

Comment: @Arvid: Please, see my edited answer, which adds a very concise and fast approach, which is based on `np.correlate`.

Comment: @PaulS. What about the condition `arr > 0`?

Comment: Thanks, @Corralien, for your comment. You are right: I missed that requirement. I am going to edit my solution accordingly.

Comment: @PaulS. Use `np.iinfo(arr.dtype).min` instead of -1000. It may be safer. If the array had been a float type, you could have used `-np.inf`

Comment: Wow, nice option @PaulS! (sorry I didn't read it earlier). And very fast! :-)

Comment: I am now looking for other applictions of correlation. This leads to a whole new rabbit hole in my work.